# Using ZFS to merge multiple drives to the same mount point

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mount, zfs

I'll start by saying I'm currently having a server with 4x6TB drives running on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm merging them together using `mergerfs`, but I suspect it is causing my server to crash very often (about every 2-3 days).

I'm looking for something else that's capable of doing this, and I wanted to know if ZFS is an option. Currently, I'm mounting each of my drives to `/mnt/` and then merging it using `mergerfs` in `fstab`.

Is something like this using ZFS possible? (If you need more info, I'd be happy to provide per your request)

Comment: Do you want the disks to remain logically separate, or do you want them to always act as one unit (spreading all data across multiple disks)? Do you have any reliability requirements?

Comment: @grawity I'm not quite familiar with the differences. I'll try describing. The disks are mounted at `/mnt` folders a-d (4 drives). I want to create a mount that will merge them all together to `/home`, so I see all data from all drives together.
I also heard about something called LVM (which I guess makes them act as one unit? And thus if one drive fails, all data is lost?)
If there's no way of keeping them separate (so if one drive fails, I won't lose the others' data), I can manage with the other option.